# How to discover custom library using Vagrant Joomlatools/box with extension:symlink to project folder

Tags: development, extensions

I'm setting up a new developers station, but I've ran into a problem getting a Joomla installer to discover my custom library. Here is a short description of the setup.

Using Vagrant, VirtualBox with Joomlatools/box installed and working
I've symlinked multiple component type extensions and discover is working fine for them.

I symlinked the library in the same fashion as the components, but extension manager discover isn't working.

I think it has something to do with were my customLibName.xml manifest (right now it is located in mylib root directory.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: O.k. So I found the answer. Took a little digging through the code, but it wasn't as difficult as I thought it would be. 

To install a library via the discover installer you need to copy the xml manifest to ROOT/administrator/manifests/libraries

Then copy the rest of your library into ROOT/libraries

After that you will able to discover it using the Joomla admin GUI.

Comment: Hi @user1955325! Please post your answer as an actual answer and accept it. This lets everyone know that your question is answered and helps others find the answer more quickly if they hit the same problem

Comment: I tried, but my rep was to low to post within 8 hours. Will do now

Comment: No problem. Just making sure!

Answer (score 4):

O.k. So I found the answer. Took a little digging through the code, but it wasn't as difficult as I thought it would be.

To install a library via the discover installer you need to copy the xml manifest to ROOT/administrator/manifests/libraries

Then copy the rest of your library into ROOT/libraries

After that you will able to discover it using the Joomla admin GUI